# Fragment is reloaded each time after rejecting location permission

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, gps

I'm asking permission to access GPS location in Fragment, but when I deny permission - fragment reloads each time. When I accept permission it's okay, fragment doesn't reload.

It was working just fine before, but started to act like this. I've tested it on different devices: the same result. What could be the problem?

In manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

```
    override fun checkAndAskPermissions() {
        val permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(permission), LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            presenter.onPermissionsReceived()
        }
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    presenter.onPermissionsReceived()
                } else {
                    presenter.onPermissionsDenied()
                }              
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should check your code on `presenter` class  `onPermissionsDenied` function.

Comment: I've tried to remove that line, but the result is the same, something wrong with onRequestPermissionResult method

Comment: interesting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in onRequestPermissionsResult method. The problem was on onResume method of activity, that this fragment was attached to. Each time permission was asked onResume method of activity was called.

Answer (score -1):

Make a boolean condition which can't be trigger more than once

```
override fun checkAndAskPermissions() {
    if(bool) {
       bool = false
       ....
    }
}
```